# How to create an rpm without a build step

Tags: rpm

I'm trying to create an rpm of some code which doesn't need to be built.  It will just need to run a script when it's installed on the destination system (i.e. I just need the %install portion of the spec file).

I've left both %build and %configure sections of my rpm spec file empty, yet rpmbuild continues to try and execute ./configure with a bunch of parameters.

Does anyone know how I can have rpmbuild create the rpm without trying to run ./configure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rpm specfile syntax is confusing. `%configure` isn't a section like `%build` is. It's a macro which expands to running `./configure` with system-specific parameters. That's what you're seeing. And the solution is easy — remove it, and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

If you do rpmbuild --short-circuit -bi /path/to/specfile, it will skip the %prep and %build stages and go straight to the %install stage.  That should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

rpmbuild -ba /path/to/specfile

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's not what I'm looking for.  The command you provided is what I've been running.  When I execute that command, it tries to run ./configure (with a bunch of params).  For this package, there is no configure script and there is no need to build anything.  I need to create an rpm that will run a script when it's installed on the destination system.

Answer (score -2):

It's a kludge, but put a noop in %build and %configure ?